# expo local notifications how to set time to start and repeat every day?

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo, local

I'm having a hard time figuring out the latest version of expo on how to setup a local notification at a specific time in the day and make it to repeat every day.

- relevant section from package.json

```
"expo": "~40.0.0",
"expo-notifications": "~0.8.2",
```

- I can create notifications using this sipets

```js
function startsTomorowButNotAbleToRepeateEvryDay() {
  let tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  tomorrow.setHours(20);
  tomorrow.setMinutes(0);

  return {
    content: {
      title: "Time to study v2",
      body: "Don't forget to study today!",
    },
    trigger: tomorrow,
  };
}

function repeatsEvryDayButNotPossibleToSetTime() {
  const seccondsInADay = 24 * 60 * 60;

  return {
    content: {
      title: "Time to study v2",
      body: "Don't forget to study today!",
    },
    trigger: {
      seconds: seccondsInADay,
      repeats: true,
    },
  };
}
```

- and this is how in use on or the other

```js
Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync(startsTomorowButNotAbleToRepeateEvryDay());
Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync(repeatsEvryDayButNotPossibleToSetTime());
```

How do I make a notification start tomorrow at a specific time and have it repeated every day?

Answer (score 5):

From Notifications.types.d.ts

```
export interface DailyTriggerInput {
    channelId?: string;
    hour: number;
    minute: number;
    repeats: true;
}
```

You can use:

```
trigger: {
    hour: 19;
    minute: 45;
    repeats: true;
}
```

Comment: What should I do, if I want this to start after a week? WHat I want is to get notification at 19:45 everyday, but only from next week(or x days).

Answer (score 0):

try as follows:

```
const schedule = new Date();  
    
   schedule.setHours(19);
   schedule.setMinutes(45);

   Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
     content: {
     title: "title txt",
     body: 'body text',
     },
     trigger:{
       schedule,
       repeats: true,
     });
```

Comment: this will only fire once!!. when the date is reached so it will never be repeated.